# It is possible for created temporary table by a stored procedure to be used in another stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which creates a temporary table with found indexes by using `CONTAINSTABLE` like (I put a piece of stored procedure code):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable(
  ID INT,
  RANK INT)

 SELECT @query = ' 
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT ID AS T_ID,
   indexTable.RANK AS RANK
  FROM 
   MyTable
  INNER JOIN
   CONTAINSTABLE(MyTable, (*), "ISABOUT('example*')") AS indexTable
  ON
   MyTable.ID = indexTable.[KEY]
  ORDER BY RANK DESC'
```

I want to use, if is possible, the temporary table into another stored procedure to use its values for other purpose and avoid to do twice same thing.

If is not possible then can you advice me the best way to re-use table data in different stored procedure. Also, I know that I cannot create view inside stored procedure then view is out of discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use GLOBAL temp tables

```
CREATE TABLE ##tmpTable(
  ID INT,
  RANK INT)
```

You can create a global temporary table by prefixing the table name with double hash(##)

Once this table has been created by a connection, like a permanent table it is then available to any user by any connection. It can only be deleted once all connections have been closed.

Edit:

In order to check for the existence of a temporary table you can use the following statement/check.

```
if object_id('tempdb..##tmpTable') is not null
begin
    drop table ##tmpTable
end
```

Comment: Then the created table by stored procedure won't be deleted at end of it execution ?

Comment: +1, Maybe also tell the OP what the differences are between global/local temp table and table variables.

Comment: @SnakeEyes: No you can use it in another procedure

Comment: Ok, great then. That temp table will be saved in `tempdb` database ? or somewhere else ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes: It will be in tempDB only

Comment: @JoeGJoseph: Also I want to ask you: I have to create `##tmpTable` every time when execute stored procedure or I have to verify if that table exists and truncate it ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes: Globaltem tables will be  destroyed along with the last connection which references them

Comment: Ok, one last question please: Is a good way to create global temp table for search/found items on home page where many people find something ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes: I think It should be OK

Answer (score 2):

If your first stored procedure *calls* the second stored procedure, the second procedure can access any temp tables that the first has created:

```
create procedure SP_1
as
    create table #T1 (ID int not null)
    insert into #T1 (ID) values (1),(2)

    exec SP_2
go
create procedure SP_2
as
    select * from #T1
go
exec SP_1
```

Produces two rows. However, I'm not sure if that's what you're trying to do - your example only defines a temp table and never accesses it.

Comment: The two stored procedures have no links between them. But is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of temporary tables a) temporary table and b) global temporary table.

Global temporary table (declared with `##` like `##globalTempTable`) can be used across all the procedures.

Normal temporary tables (declare with `#` like `#temptale`) can be used in nested procedures. If a sproc `sp_A` calls another sproc `sp_B`, a temp table declared in `sp_A` will be available in `sp_B` also.