# Why cannot create global temporary table or truncate it when call a stored procedure from C# code?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I spent whole days and hours to investigate why cannot create temporary table when I call a stored procedure from C# code.

Let's assume a piece of C# code:

```
public void GetDataByFilter(string item, string filter ...) {
   ... 
   // provide stored procedure in new SqlCommand object
   sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@val1", aValue1);
   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@val2", aValue2);
   ...
   while(sqlDataReader.Read()) { /* process info here */ }
}
```

and my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aProcedure]
  @val1 VARCHAR(255),
  @val2 VARCHAR(255),
  ...
AS 
BEGIN
  IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##aTempTable') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE tempdb..##aTempTable (
          id1 INT,
              id2 INT,
              id3 VARCHAR(255),
              ...
    )

ELSE 
    TRUNCATE TABLE tempdb..##aTempTable

    -- insert information into this table
    SELECT @paramList = ' /*list of parameters*/';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramList, ... parameters
END
```

In C# code, in **another function**, I provided

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tempdb..##aTempTable";
```

But exception was thrown that `tempdb..##aTemTable` doesn't exists.

If I execute stored procedure inside SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) then the table is created.

The problem is also for `TRUNCATE TABLE` operation **not only** for `CREATE TABLE`.

I need temporary global table for to be used into different stored procedures accordingly with [It is possible for created temporary table by a stored procedure to be used in another stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312903/it-is-possible-for-created-temporary-table-by-a-stored-procedure-to-be-used-in-a).

Any solution ?

Comment: When your session ends the global temp table is dropped. Why not just create a permanent table? It has the same possible concurrency issues but you control the lifetime.

Comment: Ok, but what's about `TRUNCATE` ? I cannot truncate table using stored procedure if it is called from C# code.

Comment: @MartinSmith: For permanent table, can I use `TRUNCATE` ? To empty the table content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that while it is possible to do what you’re describing, it is not too practical, as it presumes a lot of tricky timing: a session opens connection A and runs the proc to create the ##temp table, and that session keeps the connection open for as long as connections B, C, etc. need to be able to access the temp table.

Yould’ be better off with a solution using a “permanent” table, where a row is added with a unique identifier (int or GUID) for every “session”, that value gets returned by the initialization call (or can otherwise be retrieved or identified), and used by all subsequent calls for the session.

Comment: I cannot TRUNCATE table, the permanent table from C# code ... Why ?

Comment: I do not know. Are you truncating via your stored procedure call? I tested that, and it works for me. (Minor point, the `ELSE` covers only the single next statement (the truncate command); if you want the following two lines, `select` and `exec`, to only run if the "else" is hit, you'll need to wrap that side of the IF with BEGIN...END.)

Comment: Ah. How do you you know when to truncate? The idea with the permanent table idea is you generate a token (id) for the session, and use that token for the duration of the session. Another session would generate and use a different token (id).  You'd want to add some kind of mechanism to identify and clear out old expired sessions.

Comment: Well, you can shoot me with a gun because I made a stupid mistake. For concatenated strings, I didn't put a space between them and that why my problem occurs. TRUNCATE works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

As I alluded to in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12313043/15498) (but since you hadn't explained your scenario at the time, I didn't spell out) is that any temporary table created in one scope is accessible to any nested scope.

So, in your C# you can run the following queries:

```
CREATE TABLE #aTempTable (
      id1 INT,
          id2 INT,
          id3 VARCHAR(255),
          ...
);
```

then:

```
[dbo].[aProcedure]
```

then:

```
[dbo].[bProcedure]
```

then:

```
SELECT * from #aTempTable
```

Provided that all of these queries are run using the same `SqlConnection` object, and that the connection is kept open throughout. The first and fourth queries merely run in the scope of the connection. The two stored procedure calls run inside nested scopes.

There's no need for a global temp table. `aProcedure` can simply access `#aTempTable` (and no need to prefix any reference to it with `tempdb..` anywhere.

Comment: I cannot use temporary local table because I have many functions which call different SqlCommand object.

Comment: @SnakeEyes - You have many different functions, calling many different SqlCommands, and yet the stored procedures are all so closely related that they share result sets? Have you considered that maybe you're solving the wrong problem here?

Comment: Well, you can shoot me with a BIG gun because I made a stupid mistake. For concatenated strings, I didn't put a space between them and that why my problem occurs. TRUNCATE works perfectly